# Setup web server on Windows Server 2008?

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2008, mysql, php, amazon-ec2

I just launched an Amazon ec2 instance, with Windows Server 2008 32 bit as the OS.

I manage to connect to instance via remote control, what should I do next?

I will need to use Apache, php and mysql (and phpmyadmin). (I been using wamp all the time, till now), should I install the Wamp again? Whats your advise (previously, all these this was taken care by my hosting company, but now, i need to do it by myself).

I just need a simple web server.

I have read from xampp website (following are quoted from xampp website):

As mentioned at another place, XAMPP is not meant for production use but only for developers in a development environment. XAMPP is configured is to be as open as possible and to allow the web developer anything he/she wants. For development environments this is great but in a production environment it could be fatal.

Here a list of missing security in XAMPP:

```
The MySQL administrator (root) has no password.
The MySQL daemon is accessible via network.
phpMyAdmin is accessible via network.
The XAMPP demopage is accessible via network.
The default users of Mercury and FileZilla are known.
```

Based on this fact, should I install apache, php and mysql manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be challenging to install and configure all of that on a Windows Server, might be easier to just learn ASP.NET/C# :-D.

I've never used Wamp, but in general you'll need to:

- Download and install them all; i'd recommend putting the data directories for each on a separate EBS volume that you attache to the instance
- Make sure to configure your security group in the Amazon management console to open the ports that you'll need to get through to your server on
- Once you do get the server set up to basically how you want it, be sure to create an AMI from it so that you'll have one that you can spin up in the future and won't have to set it all up again

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although u said you never used wamp before, but i believe you have a solid background about web server hosting. I have installed xampp, run the services and test it, it can only works locally, do you have any idea how to publish it to the world(online)?

Comment: Okie, I solved it by adding a port (firewall was blocking it I guess)

Comment: Sorry, missed your comments - ya, the port needs to be open on the machine itself and also in the AWS console in your Security Group.  Glad you got it going!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WebMatrix](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2010/07/12/creating-php-websites-with-webmatrix.aspx) to install/configure your PHP stack on Windows. Also, there's no need to build your own MySQL Servers as you can use [RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/) which makes it VERY easy to manage a MySQL environment without having to deal with things like replication and backups manually.

Comment: I alreadt setup an ec2 instance, but i installed everything in that instance, which I realize is not very good. Like you pointed out, I should use the RDS. Do you have any idea, how to link my ec2 to RDS? (I am new to amazon web service)